# to built a new R package fails: Win10, RStudio

Tags: r

I want to build a new own package in RStudio Version 1.1.383 (Windows 10).

I installed Rtools and devtools. I created a new project including the sources and Rcpp functions. Then I clicked "Clean and Rebuild".

The system output:

```
==> Rcpp::compileAttributes()

* Updated R/RcppExports.R

==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source depcoeff

* installing to library 'o:/eckhard/stat/R/lib'
* installing *source* package 'depcoeff' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
Warnung in system(paste(cmd, "shlib-clean")) 'make' not found
Warnung in system(cmd) 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'depcoeff'
* removing 'o:/eckhard/stat/R/lib/depcoeff'

Exited with status 1.

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed.
Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
```

---

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Whats your installation path of Rtools? If you have selected your own path during installation, then you have to modify the path environment variable. For example, I have installed it under `C:\Rtools`. So my path variable is `C:\Rtools\bin`.

Comment: I did so. I set the variable PATH by: Sys.setenv(PATH =
Then the error still occurs.

Comment: I did the whole procedure again. I installed Rtools from CRAN, set the PATH variable. An error occurs again and RStudio recommends to install Rtools!!??

Comment: I did the whole procedure again. I installed Rtools from CRAN, set the PATH variable. An error occurs again and RStudio recommends to install Rtools!!??

Moreover, the R console gives:
find_rtools(T)
Scanning R CMD config CC...
cc_path:  
'' does not exist
Scanning path...
Scanning registry...
Found C:/Program Files/Rtools for 3.0 
Found C:/Program Files/Rtools for 3.1 
Found C:/RBuildTools/3.4 for 3.4 
Found C:/Rtools for 3.5 
VERSION.txt
Rtools version 3.5.0.4 
[1] TRUE

Comment: Did you set/check the PATH variable via Windows system propertys -> environment variables? If you are working with the `rcpp` package I think you may also set the PATH variable to the compiler (something like C:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin)